# This method is not supported by this class error @ client.DownloadFile

Tags: c#, download, webclient, system.net.webexception, system.net.httpwebrequest

I get this strange error suddenly saying `System.Net.WebException : The request was abborted: The Request was canceled. ---> System.NotSupportedException : This method is not supported by this class` . I dont know why is occurring cause it used to  work fine.

I tried searching online but found no help on this matter. the follwing is the method that that i am having pronlems with and i have pointed out the line that gives out the error.

```
    //get column heading names from formatted text file
    public string getFTextColumnHead(string serverURL, string userName, string password, int headRow,
                                     string filePath, string reqFrom)
    {
        string line = "";
        //initialize WebClient object
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        //if the request is for web
        if (reqFrom == "web")
        {
            //send web request to retreive the data from the url
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(serverURL);
            //parse credentials to the web server to authenticate
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
            //Grab Data from the web server and save to the given path
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri(serverURL), filePath);//<---exception occurs here
        }
        //initialize input output stream and open the downloaded file
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath);
        //loop through the rows of the file until the column heading row is reached
        for (int i = 0; i < headRow; i++)
        {
            //read the line
            line = file.ReadLine();
        }
        //dipoase the client
        client.Dispose();
        //return the column heading string
        return line;
    }
```

Thank you guys. I am closing in my deadline for this project. all this happened right in the last moment. help is very much appreciated :)

P.S. I installed `Resharper` to review the code. but i did not make any changes it suggested to this particular class :).

Comment: Is this being called by multiple threads (or multiple web requests) at the same time? The documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194.aspx says that you can get an NotSupportedException when "The method has been called simultaneously on multiple threads."

Comment: @JonVD hi, thank you for the reply. No, i just have this method which deals with downloading files. also this used to work fine until few days back :( .. i completed my project and when i try to submit this occurs :( such a headache

Comment: how are the arguments passed in being formatted? in particular serverURL.

Comment: Have you tried just using the following?: client.DownloadFile(serverURL, filePath);

Comment: @JohnFaulkner Hi, thanx for the reply. I went into debugging mode put on few breakers and checked. the arguments are passed fine. i used the values generated from the system to manually login and it was successful.

Comment: @JuStDaN Hi, thanx for the reply, yes i will try that and post back :)

Comment: @JuStDaN I tried it but, i get the same error :(

Comment: does serverURL include the http:// prefix?

Comment: I would be checking your serverURL as John suggested, also make sure that you have the file name appended on the end. Other then that, I can't see any issue besides the redundant HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(serverURL); (which could also be used with WebResponse to download a file).

Comment: @JohnFaulkner i will check as soon as i get back to work on monday :) thanks again for the info :)

Comment: @JuStDaN thanks for the tip man :) will check again